# Using IN() clause resulting in Filesort

Tags: mysql, explain, filesort

I have a simple table ->

```sql
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
by_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
posted_on INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

My table engine is `MyISAM`.

I have a multiple column index called `combo1` on `by_id,posted_on,id`

I run this query ->

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM books 
        WHERE by_id = '1' AND posted_on = '0' 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7;
```

The `Extra` column says `Using where` and key column says `combo1`

But, when i run this query ->

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM books 
        WHERE by_id IN(1,7,10) AND posted_on = '0' 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7;
```

The `Extra` column says `Using where; Using filesort` and key column says `combo1`.

Why is a `filesort` occuring in second case even though the QEP shows that optimizer is using the index combo1 which has 'id' indexed in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index is a B+ tree. That means that under the by_id 1 there are all records with posted_on 0 and by_id 1, and then you have all the ids for those records. Under the by_id 7 however you have another tree branch, that contains records with posted_on 0 and they contains the records with their ids.

When you have in clause, you are retrieving 3 different branches of the tree, you have to merge them and resort them, since ids with 1,2,4 may be under by_id 1, but 3,5 under by_id 10; MySQL retrieves 1,2,4,3,5 and have to resort them.

In the first case there is only one branch, and each branch is already sorted

Comment: please tell if i should then remove `id` from combo1 index.. @Darhazer

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if MySQL takes advantage that the branches are already ordered and applies merge_sort or not; maybe it depends on the version as well. Without proper benchmarking, I would preserve id in the index. On the other hand, if the table was InnoDB, id is included at the end of every secondary index. This is taken into account in sorting only in MySQL 5.6, if I remember correctly.